# Where am I supposed to enter lines that begin with =# for Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
$ mix ecto.create
** (Mix) The database for HelloPhoenix.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

According to the Phoenix page on [Mix Tasks](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/mix-tasks), the remedy to the above problem is to enter `=# CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN CREATEDB;`

But what I don't get is where to put this. Is it something that I enter in a file? If so, which file? Is it a command that I run on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This need to be run in the PostgreSQL command line tool. From your terminal, run:

`psql --username=postgres`

Then once you are in the psql command line you can run the command **without** the `=#`. The latter is used to indicate the start of the command prompt in the example:

`CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN CREATEDB;`